# Consuming RabbitMQ Queue in IIS hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, rabbitmq

I have a WCF service hosted on IIS, where during application initialization it start listening to the RabbitMQ and it subscribed to the Q say Q1, after long run of the service, we are seeing that the service is fetching the messages and it fails to processing it.

But we do have the different windows service which is also interested in the same events which is subscribed to the different Q say Q2, was able to process all the events even after a long run.

Why does the WCF is failing after long run, is there a thread pool sealing which will be imposed on Apppool ? Need help in debugging this.

Note: Both Queues (Q1 and Q2) are subscribing to the same message rout keys which is connected to the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure about processing, but by default IIS-hosted anything AppPools recycle/expire after 20 minutes so it's entirely possible your WCF service is no longer running if its service methods have not been invoked.

Try setting your IIS AppPool timeout to `0` to disable timeout.

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention we have the setting AppPool timeout to 0 only

Comment: Don't forget to create a custom service host and make your AppPool autostart

Comment: Can you please elaborate how this will help in this scenario? Because custom service host will be useful when we do a self hosting right ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory?view=netframework-4.7.1.   No its not that sort of custom host.  This one is a special one for IIS